# Insertions replace other insertions in array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, switch-statement

I am trying to make a chess board and when I try to insert a piece, the pieces inserted before are replaced with the new piece inserted.

For example, if I insert a tower and then insert a horse, the tower transforms into a horse. (I can't see the error).

```
public Board() {
    this.board = new Position[row][columns];
}

for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <= 3; j++) {
        if (i == 0) {
             switch (j) {
                 case 0 : pieza0 = new Pieza (PiezasTipo.TORRE,PiezasColor.NEGRO);
                          pieza0.setId();
                          this.tablero[i][j].setPieza(pieza0);

                          pieza0 = new Pieza(PiezasTipo.TORRE, PiezasColor.NEGRO);
                          pieza0.setId();
                          this.tablero[i][fila-j].setPieza(pieza0);

                          pieza0 = new Pieza(PiezasTipo.TORRE, PiezasColor.BLANCO);
                          pieza0.setId();
                          this.tablero[columna-i][j].setPieza(pieza0);

                          pieza0 = new Pieza(PiezasTipo.TORRE, PiezasColor.BLANCO);
                          pieza0.setId();
                          this.tablero[columna-i][fila-j].setPieza(pieza0);

                  case 1 : pieza0 = new Pieza(PiezasTipo.CABALLO, PiezasColor.NEGRO);
                           pieza0.setId();
                           this.tablero[i][j].setPieza(pieza0);

                           pieza0 = new Pieza(PiezasTipo.CABALLO, PiezasColor.NEGRO);
                           pieza0.setId();
                           this.tablero[i][fila-j].setPieza(pieza0);

                           pieza0 = new Pieza(PiezasTipo.CABALLO, PiezasColor.BLANCO);
                           pieza0.setId();
                           this.tablero[columna-i][j].setPieza(pieza0);

                           pieza0 = new Pieza(PiezasTipo.CABALLO, PiezasColor.BLANCO);
                           pieza0.setId();
                           this.tablero[columna-i][fila-j].setPieza(pieza0);
```

I insert all towers (4: two black and two white) and then the inserted horses and towers transform into horses. Is this an instance problem or do all pieces have the same memory direction? I don't know.

Comment: I don't see any columna and fila in your code posted but I think that because you use array, if you use [] to get a position in array, if you change it, the change will replace old value in that position. no insertion for built in array (i mean Position[][]) happen. you must do it by self with a new copy of array or you can use something like ArrayList if you like to have insert. (ArrayList has lots of other feature.

Comment: I think the issue is that you insert the figure on the same place, but if it tower it should be placed near to horse but not on him.
Also, you can add a method that will check if there is a figure on that place and if so that you shouldn't place there a new figure

Answer (score 2):

I think the (or at least one of the) reason why a `PiezasTipo.TORRE` is transforming into a `PiezasTipo.CABALLO` in your expected output is due to a missing `break;` statement in the `case` block. If there is no `break` statement, after it is done executing the `case 0` block of code, it will continue into the `case 1` block.

[Here is a link for a more thorough overview of the switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).